# Second media query isnt loading

Tags: css

The media query with min-width 845px and max-width 930px isn't loading up in browser.
Am i Doing anything wrong below ?

```css
@media screen and (max-width:845px){
    .btn{
        margin-top: 15px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:845px) and (max-width:930px){
    .btn{
        margin: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Below is the HTML Code : 
Its a simple angularjs page which checks for prime number after a number is entered.
Note: my2.css has nothing.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Is It A Prime Number ?</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my2.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <h1 class="display-1" align="center">Angular JS - Prime Number</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-controller="mycontroller">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="numberinput">Email number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberinput" ng-model="no">
                    <input type="button" style="margin: 2px" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isitprime()" value="Check">
                </div>
            </form>
            <br><br>
            <span class="lead" id="spanid" style="color: {{str}}">
                {{no1}}{{message}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the javascript I am using :

```js
var obj = angular.module('myapp', []);
obj.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.no = '';
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.str = 'black';
    $scope.isitprime = function () {
        var isPrime = true;
        if ($scope.no == 1)
        {
            isPrime = false;
        } else if ($scope.no == 2)
        {
            isPrime = true;
        } else
        {
            for (var x = 2; x < sqrt($scope.no); x++)
            {
                if ($scope.no % x == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
            }

        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
            $scope.message = ' is a prime number';
            $scope.str = 'green';
        } else
        {
            $scope.message = ' is not a prime number';
            $scope.str = 'red';
        }
    };
});
```

Below is the screenshot :

[image: screenshot google chrome browser]

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem if you don't give us the HTML? Look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your media query is fine, but your `margin: auto !important;` will overwrite `margin-top: 15px !important;`. Look below for a fix.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:845px){
    .btn{
        color: blue;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:845px) and (max-width:930px){
    .btn{
        color: red;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hello</button>
```

Comment: This didnt work out. After making this edit, I saved it and reloaded the page and went to chrome developer console >> Elements >> Styles. There was only one media query that is the first one and the second media query was not found

Comment: If you resize the window you can see the button is changing. Please make sure your window size is between 845px and 930px or else you will not see this media query taking into effect.

Comment: It is working in your code sample. I have included all my code after editing the question. You can try to find out whats wrong there. Thanx for your time .

Comment: @PratikSolanki It should be working fine. What device are you using, can you screenshot your app with device profile with a window size set to 900px?

Comment: @PratikSolanki Can you show me the elements / styles tab in dev console